# To maximize the size of listview in c#

Tags: c#

I have a listview .On clicking a button i want to maximize the size of listview.Can anybody help to get a way to maximize the listview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to set explicitly the width and height you can use `DockStyle.Fill` mode to automatically stretch the all window area.

> ```
> listview1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
> ```

---

**Edit:** if you want the listview to be full screen, you need to container window to be full screen.

To do that you can use:

> ```
> this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
> this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
> this.TopMost = true;
> ```

Where this referred to the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height and width of the list box the same as you can for any other windows control.

Comment: is there any way to make listbox full screen?

Comment: You would need to make the window full screen